# How to grep for "string\tstring"?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need to search a large group of data files.  I want to find files that contain the string "foo\tbar\tboo".  I have tried this ...

```
$ find . -name "foo*dat" -exec grep foo {} \; | less
          "miscinfo_foo" => [
                               "foo\tbar\tnot_foo"
                                      "miscinfo_foo",
          "miscinfo_foo" => [
                               "foo\tbar\tyes_foo"
                                      "miscinfo_foo",
```

But if I do ...

```
$ find . -name "foo*dat" -exec grep -E "foo\tbar" {} \;
```

... I get no output. I have tried egrep too. I have tried escaping the `\t` with `\\t` but still get no output.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try `'foo\\tbar'` or other variations in `''` instead of `""`.  I think the `\t` you are looking for is literal text, not an escape sequence, so you need to protect the literal backslash from bash processing.

Comment: Thanks cxw. That works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
find . -name "foo*dat" -exec grep -E 'foo\\tbar' {} \;
                                     ^   ^     ^
```

in single quotes rather than double, and with an extra backslash.  The `''` prevent `bash` from processing backslashes, so that `grep` will actually see `foo\\tbar`.  Based on your output, I think you are looking for the literal text backslash-tee, not an ASCII character 9, so double the backslash to have `grep` match it as literal text.

Comment: The `-E` is doing nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are two effects at play here:

1. grep understands that `\t` means a tab character.
2. The shell will expand `\\` to `\` within a double-quoted string.

You want the slash to be escaped, so you need to pass `\\t` to grep within single quotes:

```
grep 'foo\\tbar'
```